# trying to sum allocation percentages

Tags: sql

I am a newbie with SQL and was thrown into this with little training, so very simple answers are appreciated! I am trying to pull a query of participant allocations but I need all the alloctions for each fun summed together. I currently have the following:

```
select external_plan,
   participant_tax_id,
   external_vehicle,
sum (decimal(alloc_rate,15,2)),
   money_type
from trc.vst_partalloc
where external_plan='RF00580'
and money_type='101'
group by alloc_rate,
     external_plan,
   participant_tax_id,
   external_vehicle,
   money_type
```

this returns the following example:

```
EXTERNAL_PLAN   PARTICIPANT_TAX_ID  EXTERNAL_VEHICLE    Alloc_Rate    MONEY_TYPE

RF00580                  #########  DFCEX              0.03 101
RF00580                  #########  ACRNX              0.06 101
RF00580                  #########  STSVX              0.06 101
RF00580                  #########  VISGX             0.06  101
RF00580                  #########  VMVIX              0.06 101
RF00580                  #########  RERGX              0.09 101
RF00580                  #########  DODGX             0.12  101
RF00580                  #########  DRLCX              0.12 101
RF00580                  #########  ABNAK             0.20  101
RF00580                  #########  PTTRX              0.20 101
```

So the `#########` represents one participant across these rows, the alloc rate adds up to 100, what I need is to have one row returned not displaying the `external_vehicle` but summing up the `alloc_rate` to 100 - does that make sense? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I should have proofed this before I submitted, arrghh - I mean I need all the allocations for the fund ids summed together to equal 100%

Comment: It's not clear exactly what combination of data adds up to 100, or how, please explain some more :)

Comment: What does this "allocation_rate" in your input data row actually represent?  And are you trying to report what proportion of the group each result row represents, such that all the result rows for a given external_plan will add up to 100% ?

Comment: Is this a general vendor independent question?  If you are trying to solve it for your particular database, please tell us which database package you are working with, such as Oracle, DB2, Microsoft SQL Server, MS-Access, mySQL, or what.  The version would probably help too, if you know it.

Comment: I am working with WinSQL. Sorry I know it's clear as mud. I am trying to pull participant investment elections in mutual funds out of our database. Right now I am able to pull by each mutual fund, but what I need to pull is just the sum of all the mutual funds added together, which may or may not add up to 100%.

Comment: You said you need 1 result row, showing a sum of 100%.  Why?  Is this to check the allocation rates to make sure they add up properly?  And might your report have more than one plan, each adding up to 100%?  Or are you only picking one plan & one money type?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need to do is remove External_vehicle from the select and group by clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to remove `external_vehicle` amd `alloc_rate` from the `group by`:

```
select external_plan, participant_tax_id,
       sum (decimal(alloc_rate,15,2)),
       money_type
from trc.vst_partalloc
where external_plan='RF00580' and money_type='101'
group by external_plan, participant_tax_id, money_type
```

Some comments:

(1) You don't need to include external_plan and money_type in both the `where` clause and the `group by` clauses.  If you are limiting them to a single value, you can use the query:

```
select participant_tax_id,
       sum (decimal(alloc_rate,15,2))
from trc.vst_partalloc
where external_plan='RF00580' and money_type='101'
group by participant_tax_id
```

(2) Assuming that `alloc_rate` is a numeric type, you are doing the conversion for output purposes.  You should do the conversion *after* the sum:

```
select external_plan, participant_tax_id,
       decimal(sum (alloc_rate),15,2),
       money_type
from trc.vst_partalloc
where external_plan='RF00580' and money_type='101'
group by external_plan, participant_tax_id, money_type
```

Comment: Did she say she only wanted one plan and one money type?  We don't know her underlying database system.  I don't know what your primary system is, but on mine a grouping SELECT cannot show non-aggregate columns that are not part of the GROUP BY clause, so your second query (1) would not be allowed.

Comment: @WarrenT . . . The example query in the question selects one plan and one money type.  Seems pretty clear to me.  And, thank you for pointing out the error in the second query.  I removed the `money_type` column that I inadvertently left in.

Comment: yes that was the example. But just because there was only one in the example, I'm not sure if we can assume that in the real file that there might not be other cases not shown. An example is frequently trimmed down for brevity. Just sayin ;-)